# Typesetting the title in the center of page using geometry package

Tags: titles, geometry

I would like to put the title in the center of the page and to have it typeset in "Huge" font. I have the titles of the chapters typeset in "Huge" font. Why is the title of the document not typeset in "Huge" font.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}

%Some packages
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for "\texorpdfstring" command
\usepackage{enumitem}

\allowdisplaybreaks


%This package allows Chapter titles to be single spaced.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\setstretch{0.2}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\setstretch{0.2}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\onehalfspacing}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{40pt}{\huge}
%\titleformat{\section}{\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\onehalfspacing}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


%These make top, right, bottom margins confirming to the requirements
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.0in,%
left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry} %, showframe

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% small stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{footnote}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black}}


%Does not count introduction when numbering theorems, etc.
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

%Makes page numbers appear
\pagestyle{plain}



\begin{document}


%Makes the page numbers roman numerals, and doesn't count these pages in the table of contents.
\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\vbox to 1truein{}



\centerline{The Rules of Arithmetic}


\newpage



\chapter{A Criterion for Equivalent Quotients}


\noindent \textbf{Theorem} \\
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ac}{bc}
\end{equation*}
{\em for any natural number $a$, $b$, and $c$.}
\vskip0.25in


This theorem can easily be extended to quotients. We illustrate the utility of the theorem and its corollary in the following examples.
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Express $\displaystyle{\frac{2.6}{6.5}}$ as a decimal.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2.6}{6.5} = \frac{2.6 \cdot 10}{6.5 \cdot 10}
= \frac{26}{65}
= \frac{2\cdot13}{5\cdot13}
= \frac{2}{5}
= 0.4. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{0.625}{0.00125}}$.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{0.625}{0.00125}
= \frac{0.625\cdot10^5}{0.00125\cdot10^5}
= \frac{625 \cdot 100}{125}
= \frac{(5 \cdot 125)100}{125}
= 5 \cdot 100
= 500. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{1.43}{0.055} + \frac{169}{0.0104}}$.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{align*}
\frac{1.43}{0.055} + \frac{169}{0.0104}
&= \frac{1.43\cdot10^3}{0.055\cdot10^3} + \frac{169\cdot10^4}{0.0104\cdot10^4} \\
&= \frac{143\cdot10}{55} + \frac{169\cdot10^4}{104} \\
&= \frac{(11\cdot13)(2\cdot5)}{5\cdot11} + \frac{13^2\cdot(8\cdot1250)}{13\cdot8} \\
&= 2 \cdot 13 + 13 \cdot 1250 \cdot \\
&= 26 + 16250 \\
&= 16276. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{align*}



\newpage


\chapter{Rule for the Addition of Quotients}


\noindent \textbf{Theorem} \\
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a + b}{c}
\end{equation*}
{\em for any natural numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$.}
\vskip0.25in



This theorem can easily be extended to quotients. We illustrate the utility of the theorem and its corollary in the following examples.
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{0.54}{0.081} + \frac{8.1}{0.243}}$.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{align*}
\frac{0.54}{0.081} + \frac{8.1}{0.243}
&= \frac{0.54 \cdot 1000}{0.081 \cdot 1000}
+ \frac{8.1 \cdot 1000}{0.243 \cdot 1000} \\
&= \frac{54 \cdot 100}{81}
+ \frac{81 \cdot 100}{243} \\
&= \frac{(2 \cdot 27)100}{3 \cdot 27}
+ \frac{81 \cdot 100}{3 \cdot 81} \\
&= \frac{2 \cdot 100}{3}
+ \frac{100}{3} \\
&= \frac{200}{3} + \frac{100}{3} \\
&= \frac{200 + 100}{3} \\
&= \frac{300}{3} \\
&= \frac{3 \cdot 100}{3} \\
&= 100. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty weird. Why don't you use the `amsthm` package to define the various environments such as `Theorem` and `Example`?

Comment: The overfull box warnings are due to the `minipage` environments.

Comment: @Stephen  I removed the `minipage` environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\newgeometry`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}

%Some packages
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{sectsty} % not with titlesec
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  bindingoffset=0.0in,
  left=1.5in,
  right=1in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  footskip=.25in,
  %showframe,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black}}


\urlstyle{same}
\allowdisplaybreaks


%This package allows Chapter titles to be single spaced.
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\setstretch{0.2}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\setstretch{0.2}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\onehalfspacing}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{40pt}{\huge}
%\titleformat{\section}{\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

%\allsectionsfont{\onehalfspacing}% not with titlesec

%Makes page numbers appear
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}


%Makes the page numbers roman numerals, and doesn't count these pages in the table of contents.
\frontmatter

\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-\topskip}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{\Huge\bfseries The Rules of Arithmetic}
\vspace*{\fill}
\restoregeometry

\mainmatter


\chapter{A Criterion for Equivalent Quotients}


\noindent \textbf{Theorem} \\
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ac}{bc}
\end{equation*}
{\em for any natural number $a$, $b$, and $c$.}
\vskip0.25in


This theorem can easily be extended to quotients. We illustrate the utility of the theorem and its corollary in the following examples.
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Express $\displaystyle{\frac{2.6}{6.5}}$ as a decimal.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2.6}{6.5} = \frac{2.6 \cdot 10}{6.5 \cdot 10}
= \frac{26}{65}
= \frac{2\cdot13}{5\cdot13}
= \frac{2}{5}
= 0.4. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{0.625}{0.00125}}$.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{0.625}{0.00125}
= \frac{0.625\cdot10^5}{0.00125\cdot10^5}
= \frac{625 \cdot 100}{125}
= \frac{(5 \cdot 125)100}{125}
= 5 \cdot 100
= 500. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{1.43}{0.055} + \frac{169}{0.0104}}$.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{align*}
\frac{1.43}{0.055} + \frac{169}{0.0104}
&= \frac{1.43\cdot10^3}{0.055\cdot10^3} + \frac{169\cdot10^4}{0.0104\cdot10^4} \\
&= \frac{143\cdot10}{55} + \frac{169\cdot10^4}{104} \\
&= \frac{(11\cdot13)(2\cdot5)}{5\cdot11} + \frac{13^2\cdot(8\cdot1250)}{13\cdot8} \\
&= 2 \cdot 13 + 13 \cdot 1250 \cdot \\
&= 26 + 16250 \\
&= 16276. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{align*}


\chapter{Rule for the Addition of Quotients}


\noindent \textbf{Theorem} \\
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a + b}{c}
\end{equation*}
{\em for any natural numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$.}
\vskip0.25in



This theorem can easily be extended to quotients. We illustrate the utility of the theorem and its corollary in the following examples.
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Example} \vskip1.25mm
Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{0.54}{0.081} + \frac{8.1}{0.243}}$.
\vskip0.2in

\noindent \textbf{Solution}
\begin{align*}
\frac{0.54}{0.081} + \frac{8.1}{0.243}
&= \frac{0.54 \cdot 1000}{0.081 \cdot 1000}
+ \frac{8.1 \cdot 1000}{0.243 \cdot 1000} \\
&= \frac{54 \cdot 100}{81}
+ \frac{81 \cdot 100}{243} \\
&= \frac{(2 \cdot 27)100}{3 \cdot 27}
+ \frac{81 \cdot 100}{3 \cdot 81} \\
&= \frac{2 \cdot 100}{3}
+ \frac{100}{3} \\
&= \frac{200}{3} + \frac{100}{3} \\
&= \frac{200 + 100}{3} \\
&= \frac{300}{3} \\
&= \frac{3 \cdot 100}{3} \\
&= 100. \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

I reorganized your preamble to have package loading first and options later. Don't use both `titlesec` and `sectsty`.

I have some reservations on `\setstretch{0.2}`, but my main concern is about your code for the main text: LaTeX is *not* a word processor, you'll benefit from reading some introductory manuals.

Using `\\` for ending lines is *bad* and I can assure you that I used `\noindent` inside the `document` environment perhaps a handful of times. Don't use `\vskip`: it's a primitive with a few peculiarities.

[image]

In order to add something below the centered title:

```
\frontmatter

\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-\topskip}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{\Huge\bfseries The Rules of Arithmetic}
\vbox to 0pt{
  \vspace{1in}
  \centering
  \Huge\bfseries Quotients
  \vss
}
\vspace*{\fill}
\restoregeometry

\mainmatter
```

(the rest of the code is the same)

[image]

Comment: Very nice! In the title of Chapter 1, I don't want "Quotients" to be hyphenated - at least I don't think that I want it to be hyphenated right now. How do I put it on the next line with your code? I suppose that I should have a blank line in the code instead of \\ to start a new line on the pdf file. OK. Instead of `\noindent`, what would I use to have "Example" and "Theorem" typeset on the left margin?

Comment: @user143462 in the preambule, add this `\hyphenation{quotients}`. It will forbid the hyphenation of the comma-separated words between the brackets

Comment: @user143462 I'd add `\filright` in the specifications for `\titlesec`.

Comment: @egreg
 I added `\filright`.

Comment: @egreg
 How would I add `\centerline{\Large\bfseries Quotients}` 1 inch below the title of the document while keeping the title in the center of the first page?

Comment: @user143462 I added a possible way.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for making this additional edit.